# Jquery height Toggle with More &Less

Tags: jquery

I am try to toggle the class while on click function,
In a page i have 4 box and i have to include the view more option for these boxes. The below script is working when i click on view more+ but onclick the text "More + and less -" the text toggle are toggling at same time for 4 boxes. I want to be toggle only one box with text change "Less -".

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.viewMore').click(function() {
        var k = $(this).text();
        if (k == "More +" ) {
            $(".viewMore").text("Less -");
        }else {
            $(".viewMore").text("More +");
        }
        $(this).prev('.statusSection .feedScroll').toggleClass("big");
       <!-- $('.statusSection .feedScroll').toggleClass('big'); -->
    });
});
```

```css
.feedScroll {; height:100px; overflow:hidden} 
.big { min-height:500px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="statusSection">
 <div class="feedScroll">
 "Did You Hear What Happened to Charlotte King?" is the seventh ....."
 </div>
 <div class="viewMore">More +</div>
</div>
<div class="statusSection">
 <div class="feedScroll">
 "Did You Hear What Happened to Charlotte King?" is the seventh ....."
 </div>
 <div class="viewMore">More +</div>
</div>
```

Comment: var kkk = $(this).text();
    if (kkk == "More +" ) {
    $(this).text("Less -");
    }else {
    $(this).text("More +");
    }
Working fine with Code.

Comment: Other name for your variable @San? I mean there is lot of other names to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change only the text of the clicked .viewMore element, replace

```
if (k == "More +" ) {
    $(".viewMore").text("Less -");
}else {
    $(".viewMore").text("More +");
}
```

with

```
if (k == "More +" ) {
    $(this).text("Less -");
}else {
    $(this).text("More +");
}
```